# Getting context of Android inside additional classes

Tags: java, android, android-context

Created java class DBOperations i android project to realize database operations but found that some operations need Context object. Couldn't get it with **this** or **getapplicationcontext** method. I decided to pass context object as a paramether,e.g.

```
Mymdhod(this);
```

Is it correct way or there are other methods to get application context?

Comment: This is more of a Java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all things you need the context for can be done in the constructor, consider passing the context as a parameter to the constructor and immediately initialize everything you need the context for.

Otherwise, if you need the context in a public method, pass the context as a parameter to this method.

What you shouldn't be doing is keeping a reference to the context as a member variable. The reference you are holding might be invalidated upon traversal through the activity lifecycle and holding the reference might cause memory leaks as further described in [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you need the context in your own classes, the best way is to pass it in like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters of the method calls , you can pass the context of activity and use them in another classes. 
For instance:
    Obj.methodName(context)

And method

```
  public methodName(Context context){
 // do something with context

 }
```